# is this use of "convene" unusual but correct?

Tags: meaning

Can you write: "the International Partnership on Religion and Development which convenes UN agencies, bilateral donors and faith actors"?

Comment: Please tell us in your own words what you mean to say.  Your use of ‘convenes’ seems wrong, but I have no idea what the whole sentence is trying to say.

Comment: It's in fact in a text I am translating. I am not responsible for the original in English but I came across that sentence and thought it was wrong. Before notifying the author, I made a thorough research to see if there could exist an unusual use of the word, which would mean "is comprised of". That's what the sentence means.

Answer (score 1):

Better to say "brings together"

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's what the text I came accross meant, and I wanted to check if there could be an usual use of "convene" that could mean that too.